# How to compare a DateTime to a string

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have string which contains a time (obtained from a DB):

```
string user_time = "17:10:03"; //Hours:minutes:seconds
DateTime time_now = DateTime.Now;
```

How do I compare this string to a DateTime? I'd like something like this:

```
if(time_now > user_time)
{
    //Do something
}
else
{
  //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

DateTime supports comparison, but first you need to parse the date-time string, [DateTime.Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) should suffice:

```
var dateTimeStr = "17:10:03";
var user_time = DateTime.Parse( dateTimeStr );
var time_now = DateTime.Now;

if( time_now > user_time )
{
  // your code...
}
```

Bear in mind, that comparing dates/times sometimes requires awareness of time-zones to make the comparison meaningful.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that DateTime.Now includes a date, "17:10:03" doesn't.  Do it like this:

```
    Dim dbaseTime As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse("17:10:03")
    If DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay > dbaseTime Then
        Console.WriteLine("Let's go home")
    End If
```

Do everything in your power to convert that string column type to a datetime column.

Comment: Hans, that isn't actually a problem, since when passing a string that contains only a time to `DateTime.Parse(string)`, the method assumes the current date, so it can be compared to `DateTime.Now` without any issues.

Comment: @Allon: ah, didn't realize that.  I wonder of the next guy that maintains the code knows it too.

Comment: The next guy probably won't spot that potential "gotcha" (I didn't), but if he has a keen eye like you and he does spot it, he'll wonder what the date will be set when parsing a string that only has the time, and find the answer when checking MSDN article for `DateTime.Parse(string)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DateTime.Compare()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare(v=VS.71).aspx) along with [DateTime.Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) to convert the string to a DateTime object.

Comment: No he can't because he doesn't have an instance of `DateTime`.

Comment: @stakx, `DateTime.Parse` was not part of this answer initially, at least not at the time I posted my comment.

Answer (score 1):

[DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) Will convert the string into a DateTime object which you can then use to compare.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (DateTime.Now > DateTime.Parse(user_time))
{
   ...
}
```

But you really shouldn't store a time as a string, you should use the native time or datetime format of your database, that way you could use the value of the time in your queries, and index them properly.

Comment: I'm guessing that's a user input that the OP's validating - otherwise yes, lets hope that isn't from a database.

Comment: Before the question was edited, he explicitly said that he was getting a string form the database, and that string contained the time he wanted to use in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (time_now > Date.Parse(DBString)) {

} else {

}
```