# How to compare datetime in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have been trying to get the code to work for more then 2 hours, then I tried this site, well there is alot of code here! I have used each of them. Some are in `jQuery` while some were pure `JavaScript`.

Here is two of the code that I have tried:

**First code:** This code was caught from this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2725097/1762944

```
var dateTimeStr = "17:10:03";
var user_time = DateTime.Parse( dateTimeStr );
var time_now = DateTime.Now;
if( time_now > user_time )
 {
  // your code...
 }
```

**Second code:** This one is jQuery. It worked for the asker, and was marked as answer too. It works I have checked the fiddle provided by him! But when I tried the code, it didn't work either. Here:

```
function time_until() {
 currentTime = Math.floor(jQuery.now() / 1000);
 seconds = eventTime - currentTime;
   if(second == 0){
    //Stop voting
   }
 days = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24));
  $('#time').html('seconds ' + seconds + '<br/>days ' + days);
}
```

I have tried to edit them both. But they don't work.

**Reason why they work:** The reason behind this all, is that what I want to do is,

1. I have a database table which is storing the time for users. I mean when they made an activity such like posting status updates!
2. I have created a timestamp. Which shows perfectly like this: `few seconds ago`.
3. Now what I want is, to update the time to `1 minute ago` without reloading the page, like Facebook does. Or whatever the time is, to get updated to the next minute or hour or corresponding.

What I have tried is almost next to everything. But I guess the only issue with my codes is that when I place the `DateTime.Now` value from Database in it, it shows an error. The error is hidden so I have created an `else` statement like this:

```
if(seconds < 60) {
  $("#jstime").html(seconds + "seconds..");
// else if minutes, if hours they are all written..and then an else 
} else {
 $("#jstime").html("Again an error, try again bud");
}
```

I have a `setInterval` which keeps on updating the id with the error text.

Here is the code that I am using.

```
<span id="timeval" title="@timeStamp">@TimeStamp</span></div>
<input type="hidden" id="time" value="9/23/2013 8:10:40 PM" />
<span>Real time: @TimeStamp</span><br>
<span id="update">Updated time: no update till now;</span><br>
<span id="jstime">Time</span>
```

The `timeval` is the real time that is being shown to the users, `input` is the time from where I get the value of the time on each post, the next span just shows the time to me, I mean I used this to check what was the time when the page was loaded, `update` is the span to show the updated time, `jstime` can also be used to show the updated time.

Comment: Have a look at http://momentjs.com/

Comment: That's good! :) can you tell me..why is this happening? `34.4159` why is this still giving me a digit? while I am using this :) `var seconds = Math.floor(curTime - Time) / (60 * 1000);`

Comment: The code in your first link/sample was using .Net DateTime APIs. The JavaScript equivalents are: [`Date.parse()`](http://www.javascripture.com/Date#parse) and [`Date.now()`](http://www.javascripture.com/Date#now)

Comment: Hi, a code is working but its giving me a decimal value, you can see that above in my comment! @nkron, any guess why? even though `floor` should give me nearest whole number. But its giving me a decimal

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you stored currentTime in the function you call every n seconds. As it gets looped it will everytime create a new current time.

Make it a global variable so you can loop through the function without creating the time new and use the old time instead.

Comment: Yes, I have always been having a universal variable. Can you please help me in this? `var seconds = Math.floor(curTime - Time) / (60 * 1000);` I am using this. But still I am getting a decimal value. Like this: `34.4159` would `Math.floor` provide me `34` only?

Comment: Math.Floor(curTime - Time) -> correct, this gives you an integer which is rounded DOWN. However you then take this and divide it by (60 *1000) which could be giving you a float again.

Comment: Update: to round it all down Math.floor((curTime-Time) / (60*1000));

Answer (score 1):

Please go to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363764/how-to-compare-two-datetime-in-javascript/21855029#21855029) on stackoverflow and see my answer  on how can we compare two dates along with the time in Javascript.